# How write script that prints Filename and its Owner

Tags: linux, bash

Help to write script.
How to Using Loop, print Filename and its Owner in current directory

Example:

````
 filename: file1, owner: sysadm
 filename: file2, Owner: sysadm```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need for a loop, but implementations of `stat` differ.  On Linux, you can probably just do:

```
stat -c 'Filename: %-40N  owner: %U' *
```

On Macos, you may want to use:

```
stat -f 'Filename: %-40N  owner: %Su' *
```

Comment: thank you very much. Could you help do it with loop too

Comment: `for f in *; do stat -c 'Filename: %N, owner: %U' "$f"; done`

Answer (score 0):

awk implicitly loops over its input

```
ls -al |awk '/^-/ {print "Filename:",$9 ", Owner:",$3}'
```

Comment: thank you very much. Could you help do it with loop too  @stark

Comment: See [why not parse the output of ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) if that's what you have in mind.